# Scala, reflecting on a field so it can know its own name with lazy eval

Tags: scala, reflection

Im currently trying to refine a Dsl, and what I would like to do is for a predefined field type to be able to 'know' its own name.  I can achieve this using override def delayedInit(body: => Unit) and reflection but I would like this to support lazy eval for recursive data structures.

So I have a crude approach as follows:

```
class NamedProperty {
  var name:String = ""
}

class HasNamed extends App {
  val myName = new NamedProperty

  lazy val thisWontWork = new NamedProperty

  override def delayedInit(body: => Unit) = {
    body
    this.getClass.getMethods.foreach(m =>
      if (classOf[NamedProperty].isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType) && m.getTypeParameters.isEmpty) {
        m.invoke(this) match {
          case prop:NamedProperty =>
            prop.name = m.getName
          case _ =>
        }
      }
    )  
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the above will resolve the lazy thisWontWork property, where as I would need it to resolve its name only once it has been called

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.warski.org/blog/2012/12/starting-with-scala-macros-a-short-tutorial/) goes over creating something similar, using Scala's macros.

Comment: Cant quite see how to apply the learnings there as the property is explicitly debugged after initialization

Comment: So you want `myName.name` to return `"myName"`, and `thisWontWork.name` to return `"thisWontWork"`, right? Or am I missing something

Comment: And will `NamedProperty` include other members?

Comment: NamedProperty could include other members but only name needs to be 'injected'. Also yes myName.name should return myName

Comment: The macro he created in the blog let you call `debug(p)` to print `p=1`. The "p" in the output was "injected" via the macro. I'm thinking you might be able to adopt the approach so that the NamedProperty constructor becomes replaced by a macro, grabbing the name from the value declaration next to it. That said, I'm not experienced with macros so I can't help much there - just trying to give a possible extra route to explore.

Comment: It was that grabbing the name next it that's the problem. I don't think the macro would have any way to reference it.

Comment: An annotation macro, perhaps. Like `@named val myName` which could expand it to something like `val myName = new NamedProperty { override val name = "myName" }`.